# how to read record count while unloading from redshift to s3 in airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, airflow, record-count

I am using unload operator from [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/redshift_to_s3_operator.html) to dump data from [redshift](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/operators/redshift_to_s3_operator.html). I need to know the record count, for that i have used the option manifest, it is working good. But the problem is i need to reload this manifest file back to redshift again and read the files. I am expecting some function/code to read the count of the records while unloading from redshift and loading into s3.

Comment: Can you leverage STL_UNLOAD_LOG in Redshift?

Comment: Hey chengzhi, thank you. This solves my problem temporarily. Thnak you.

Comment: For user better understanding